# How to properly serialize a google app engine model? including datetime

Tags: google-app-engine, serialization, models

Some body can show me a workable function that can convert my models to strings? for json serialization? thanks a lot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe [Django's json libraries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) are installed on app engine by default, so you should be able to do something like:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", SomeModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: This answer might be wrong: Django serializers only work with Django models (as per [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/): "Django’s serialization framework provides a mechanism for “translating” Django models into other formats."). When coding for App Engine, it's likely that the native Datastore entities will be used (vs. Django models), in which case the `django.core.serializers` won't work.